# ActiveAdmin Collection Names

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I have an array of roles in my model:

```
ROLES = ['super_admin', 'user', 'user_admin']
```

I have an ActiveAdmin form that shows these roles:

```
input :roles, as: :check_boxes, collection: User::ROLES
```

I have to show the roles as humanized, capitalized names instead of snake case on the form:

```
Super Admin, Salesman, Sales Admin
```

but when one of them is selected, it has to be saved in snakecase.

I've tried this:

```
User::ROLES
.map { |r| "#{r.humanize}" }
.map { |r| r.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ') }
```

but this saves the role as the humanized, capitalized form instead of the snake case form. How can I use the humanized, capitalized version of the words on the form, but save the snake case version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Rails(Active Support)** method **[String#titleize](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize)** instead `split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')`

If you want to store record in DB as `snakecase` you can do below way: In dropdown option it will be displayed as `titalize` but it's value will be set as `snakecase` which will be stored in DB.

```
> roles.map{|e|[e.titleize, e]}
#=> [["Super Admin", "super_admin"], ["User", "user"], ["User Admin", "user_admin"]]
```

---

in activeadmin use:

```
input :roles, as: :check_boxes, collection: User::ROLES.map{|e|[e.titleize, e]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure Ruby, one alternative could be:

```
'super_admin'.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
#=> "Super Admin"
```

So, mapping your array:

```
roles.map { |str| [str.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' '), str] }
#=> [["Super Admin", "super_admin"], ["User", "user"], ["User Admin", "user_admin"]]
```

Backward (`before_save`):

```
"Super Admin".downcase.gsub(' ', '_') #=> "super_admin"
```